# Tienen todos los números una palabra relacionada para referirse a ellos como conjunto de unidades?

Tags: gramática

Una decena es un conjunto formado por 10 unidades. Una centena es un conjunto formado por 100 unidades. Una quincena es un conjunto formado por quince unidades. Una trecena es un conjunto formado por trece unidades.

Tienen todos los números una palabra relacionada a ellos para referirse a un conjunto de esa cantidad de números?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.** El nombre de estos conjuntos es **sustantivos numerales colectivos o de grupo** (se los ve referidos en otras partes como **números colectivos**). Existen para los primeros números naturales, para los primeros múltiplos de diez, para los múltiplos más grandes de diez con intervalos de seis órdenes de magnitud (*millón, billón, trillón...*), y para unos pocos números culturalmente importantes como el 12 y el 15.

Algunos tienen significados específicos y variantes. Por ejemplo, *quincena* no es sólo un conjunto de 15 cosas sino que se usa para designar la mitad de un mes y también el salario correspondiente; para el número 2 se usan *par* y *pareja* pero también *dúo*, pero este último generalmente refiere a personas en una banda musical o algo similar; etc.

En la mayoría de los casos los numerales colectivos (NC) son aproximativos, y muchas veces existe la ambigüedad cuando el NC va precedido a su vez por un numeral ordinal o por otro NC: si uno dice *una docena de huevos* es probable que sean exactamente 12 huevos, pero *un par de docenas de personas* es obviamente una estimación. Cuando el NC está en plural y sin determinación siempre es aproximado: *decenas de personas*, *miles de mensajes*, etc. Cuanto mayor el número mayor la imprecisión. Los hablantes no tenemos ningún motivo para crear y emplear palabras que designen, por ejemplo, conjuntos de 37 o de 1250 cosas.

La NGLE tiene una sección bastante interesante [sobre los numerales colectivos](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=pGEvgUkPmkEoNTIC) (21.3), con algunos ejemplos específicos.